# Placement of static middleware in express 4

Tags: node.js, performance, express, express-4

I see that express 4 does not need `app.use(app.router)`. This is combined with `app.get/post()`. In that case, should I define static middle-ware after all `app.[verb]()` calls?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I assume keeping it before hurts performance as each request may need file lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want it to be at the very top so that requests for files don't accidentally match routes and such.